# Find entry which has same has many

Tags: mysql, sql

I need help on wring a query which would pull an entry which has same has many.
A teacher can opt for any subjects to teach , a student can opt for any subjects to be taught.
Need to find a teacher who has opted to teach for same combination of subjects that a student has opted for.

```
Table Student

id name
1  x
2  y

Table student_Subjects

id subject_id student_id
1  1          1
2  2          1
3  1          2

Teacher

id name
1  tx
2  ty

Table teacher_subjects

id subject_id teacher_id
1  1          2
2  2          2
3  1          1

Subject

id name
1  English
2  Maths
```

Now need to find a teacher who has opted to teach same subjects as student x.

Comment: What is it? Try SQLFiddle.

Comment: What does this have to do with Java?

Comment: I was doing in java so.I will remove it now.

Comment: Ok Raptor will create all req on sqlfiddle

Comment: SQLFiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4e9eb/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(subject_id ORDER BY subject_id) as teacher_concat ,teacher_id
       FROM teacher_subjects 
       GROUP BY teacher_id 
       HAVING teacher_concat IN
                    (SELECT group_concat(subject_id ORDER BY subject_id)
                     FROM student_subjects GROUP BY student_id)
```

Comment: Thanks @rakeshjain. I had to add where student_id = idvalue to get my answer.

Comment: Can I get subjects name also along with this result. @rakeshjain